# How to fix ' ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False ;?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I'm working on faces dataset and for the pre-processing step i want to load the informations on an npy file , but i get this Error ( ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False ), how can i fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just by

```py
mat = np.load('./you_file.npy', allow_pickle=True)
```

Comment: I tried it , but a get other error ' OsError : Failed to interpret file ' npy file path ' as pickle , have u any idea how i can fix it ???

Comment: @wissam_bouattou I found that you are using windows, can you try to load the npy file in ubuntu ? I always do my jobs in ubuntu and I have never met the problem like yours. Actually, accroding to what I seach, the difference between OS might make this problem. See the link https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/issues/260#issuecomment-301770934